# Firebase - link email and sms to one user account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

First the user log in using `Google Log In`, the redirect function is :

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {

//read and save some token or ID of this user here ??
}
```

Then he must also register his phone with SMS , *separately* (by design), and it finished here after verifying his pin number :

```
confirmationResult.confirm(code).then(function (result) {
  // User signed in successfully.
  var user = result.user;

  // **** NOW I WANT TO LINK THIS NUMBER WITH THE GOOGLE EMAIL USER
```

So how I link those 2 together to have 1 user line that can log in with both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after log in with `Google` as usual, we log in the user's *phone number* but instead we use the `linkWithPhoneNumber` function, and pass the phone number of the user to it :

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.linkWithPhoneNumber("+xxxPHONExx", appVerifier)
    .then(function (confirmationResult) {
          console.log("sent");
      // SMS SENT. HERE THE USER TYPE IN HIS PIN NUMBER
      window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
    }).catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
      // Error; SMS not sent
      // ...
    });
```

Works great and creates one line with email and phone.